# How to mimic the shading effect of modal popups in Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

In Bootstrap, there's the effect of [modal popup window](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/modal/)  where the rest of the page gets inactivated (when clicking on a link, for instance) and grayed out. I'd like to mimic that effect in my own CSS.

[image: Image of modal]

After looking for a few hours into the CSS files of the package, I concluded that I won't be able to back-engineer the behavior myself. Simply too much junk in the trunk for me.

How can I mimic the described behavior in a custom way? Or did I happen to hit a very complicated issue that requires border-line black magic to get working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a div that covers the entire page with a higher z-index than your content. Make the div partially see through to get the desired look.

If you are adding a modal/popup, make sure this has a higher z-index than the backdrop.

Here's an example:

```js
$('#test').click(function() {
  var backdropHeight = $(document).height();
  $('#backdrop').css('height', backdropHeight);
  $('#backdrop').fadeIn(100, function() {
    $('#modal').fadeIn(200);
  });
});

$('#closeModal').click(function() {
  $('#modal').fadeOut(200, function() {
    $('#backdrop').fadeOut(100);
  });
});
```

```css
#backdrop {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  z-index: 10;
}

#modal {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 100px);
  top: calc(50% - 100px);
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 11;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>Hellow World</h1>
<button id="test">Show Modal</button>
<div id="modal">
  <h2>My modal</h2>
  <button id="closeModal">Close Modal</button>
</div>
<div id="backdrop"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing complicated about it. It's just a "backdrop" using an absolute positioned element with partial opacity so that elements behind it show through.

```
.backdrop {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1040;
  background-color: #000;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Demo http://www.codeply.com/go/KhCqGTSCBe

Comment: when content is huge, page will scroll in this case.

Comment: The OP didn't specify scrolling, only "inactivated when clicking on a link". In some cases they may want scrolling so this is a non issue.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the simplest solution is to override .modal-backdrop.show class.

By default it is set to:

```
.modal-backdrop.show{
    opacity: .5;
}
```

and you can just override it to

```
.modal-backdrop.show{
    opacity: 0!important; /* to disable "gray effect" */
    /* OR */
    opacity: 1;
    background: red;
    /* to change background to red */
}
```

You can change anything u want in this class

Answer (score 0):

use css position & z-index and opacity can implements modal overlay.

```js
$('input').click(function(){
  var methodName=$(this).attr('id');
   $('.modal-dialog')[methodName]();;
});
```

```css
html,body{border:0;padding:0;margin:0;}

.modal-dialog,.overlay{
 position:absolute;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 left:0;
 top:0;
}
.overlay{
 background:#000;
 opacity:0.1;
 z-index:100;
}
.dialog{
 position:absolute;
 z-index:1000;
 left:50%;
 top:50%;
}
.modal-dialog{
 display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id='fadeIn' value="Show"/>
<div class='modal-dialog'>
  <div class='dialog'>
    <input id='fadeOut' type='button' value='Cancel'>
  </div>
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```